# Svelte sapper - onMount not firing

Tags: svelte, sapper, svelte-3

I initially posted this issue [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/issues/1058) because I believed it was a bug, but I'm getting no responses.

Basically, `onMount` is not being called in my sapper routes. Maybe sapper is not hydrating my component after the server initially renders it...

`src/routes/test.svelte`

```
<script>

    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    onMount(() => {
        console.log("FOO")
    });

</script>
```

I am not seeing `FOO` in the console... any idea what the problem is?

---

Note that this code is working fine on [this svelte repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/009b3d0f6c0849ad98a76aea5ba4e601?version=3.17.1) (without sapper).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved thanks to [@artur-sim](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/issues/1058#issuecomment-575918678):

> Check client.js file there is a target object pointing to #sapper div,
>   in template html, may be you some how accidentally modified something
>   there
>
> in your client js shoud be like this
>
> ```
> import * as sapper from '@sapper/app';
>
> sapper.start({
>   target: document.querySelector('#sapper')
> });
> ```